# Data does not appear in javafx Table View

Tags: java, csv, javafx

im trying to make a GUI program using javafx. The program is supposed to take data from a csv file, store it in a public list and display it in a javafx TableView in the GUI from a controller class.

Here is the controller code

```
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import application.Main;
import application.TablaEst;

public class ControllerVer1 implements Initializable {

    public Stage stage = new Stage();

    private ObservableList<TablaEst> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private Button volverButton;

    @FXML
    private TableView<TablaEst> tableData;

    //se crean columnas
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablaEst, String> nameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablaEst, String> matCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablaEst, String> carCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablaEst, String> ingCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablaEst, String> promCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TablaEst, String> estCol;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TablaEst,String>("Nombre"));
        matCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TablaEst,String>("Matrícula"));
        carCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TablaEst,String>("Carrera"));
        ingCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TablaEst,String>("Ingreso"));
        promCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TablaEst,String>("Promedio"));
        estCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TablaEst,String>("Estatus"));
        tableData.setEditable(true);
        for (int i=0; i < (Main.estudiantes).size(); i++){
            data.add(new TablaEst(
                    (Main.estudiantes).get(i)[0],
                    (Main.estudiantes).get(i)[1],
                    (Main.estudiantes).get(i)[2],
                    (Main.estudiantes).get(i)[3],
                    (Main.estudiantes).get(i)[4],
                    (Main.estudiantes).get(i)[5]));
            //for (int j=0; j<(Main.estudiantes.get(i)).length; j++){
            //}
            System.out.println(data.get(i));
        }
        tableData.setItems(data);
    }

    @FXML
    public void volverAMain(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{
        stage = (Stage)volverButton.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/MainGUI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Here is my constructor class

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class TablaEst {
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleStringProperty mat;
    private final SimpleStringProperty car;
    private final SimpleStringProperty ing;
    private final SimpleStringProperty prom;
    private final SimpleStringProperty est;

    public TablaEst (String sName, String sMat, String sCar, String sIng, String sProm, String sEst) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(sName);
        this.mat = new SimpleStringProperty(sMat);
        this.car = new SimpleStringProperty(sCar);
        this.ing = new SimpleStringProperty(sIng);
        this.prom = new SimpleStringProperty(sProm);
        this.est = new SimpleStringProperty(sEst);
    }

    //Getter methods
    public String getName(){
        return name.get();
    }
    public String getMat(){
        return mat.get();
    }
    public String getCar(){
        return car.get();
    }
    public String getIng(){
        return ing.get();
    }
    public String getProm(){
        return prom.get();
    }
    public String getEst(){
        return est.get();
    }

    //setter methods
    public void setName(String nName){
        name.set(nName);
    }
    public void setMat(String nMat){
        mat.set(nMat);
    }
    public void setCar(String nCar){
        car.set(nCar);
    }
    public void setIng(String nIng){
        ing.set(nIng);
    }
    public void setProm(String nProm){
        prom.set(nProm);
    }
    public void setEst(String nEst){
        est.set(nEst);
    }

}
```

I have verified that my estudiantes list in the main class is reading the information from the csv, however the table still appears blank on the GUI.
Any feedback and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The line

  ```
  nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TablaEst,String>("Nombre"));
  ```

  says that the `nameCol` table column should bind the `TablaEst.NombreProperty()`, or if it doesn't exist, render the `TablaEst.getNombre()` field of the `TablaEst` instance as a cell value. Since there is no methods like these, the column will be empty.
- You are using the `SimpleStringProperty` in the TablaEst class. In addition to ordinary getters/setters, you should also add JavaFX specific getters like:

  ```
  private final SimpleStringProperty name;
  ...
  public String getName(){
      return name.get();
  }

  public void setName(String nName){
      name.set(nName);
  }

  public StringProperty nameProperty(){
      return name;
  }
  ```

  for all fields. If the tableview is going to be editable, this new getter will provide instant update to underlying TablaEst instance.
  Now you can define

  ```
  nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TablaEst,String>("name"));
  ```
- The header names for table columns should be given by setting the `text` property:

  ```
  nameCol.setText("The Nombre");
  ```

  or in FXML

  ```
  <TableColumn text="The Nombre" .... >
  ```